# Issue with a topjson object in a Meteor app built with coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, topojson

Apologies for the lack of precision in the question, but I'm not completely sure which of possibly many things I'm doing wrong here.

I'm relatively new to Coffeescript and also geo applications in general, but here goes:

I've got a working (simple) Meteor (.7.0.1) application utilizing coffeescript in both client and server.  The issue I'm having occurs when attempting to utilize TopoJSON encoded files to create a layer of US congressional districts.  (the purpose of the app is to help highlight voter suppression in the US)

So, a few things:  Typically in a non-Meteor app, I would just load the topoJSON file like so:

```
$.getJSON('./data/us-congress-113.json', function (data) {
var congress_geojson = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.districts);
congress_layer.addData(congress_geojson);
});
```

Now of course this won't work in Meteor because its not asynchronous.

One of the things that was recommended here on SO was to not worry about reading the file, and to instead change the json file to .js, and then set the contents (which are of course just an object) equal to a variable.
Here's what I did:

First, I changed the .json file to a .js file in the server directory, and added the "congress =" to the beginning of the file.  It's a huge file so forgive me for omitting the whole object.

```
congress = {"type":"Topology",
                 "objects":
                    {"districts":
                        {"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon"
```

Now here's where everything starts to give me issues:

In the server.coffee, I've created a variable like so to reference the congress object:

```
@congress_geojson = topojson.feature(congress, congress.objects.districts)
```

Notice how I'm putting the @ symbol there?  I've been told this allows a variable in Coffeescript to be globally scoped? I tried to also use a Meteor feature called "share" where I declare the variable as "share.congress_geojson". That led to the same issues which I will describe below.

Now in the client.coffee file, I'm trying to call this variable to load into a Leaflet map.

```
congress_layer = L.geoJson(null,
  style:
    color: "#DE0404"
    weight: 2
    opacity: 0.4
    fillOpacity: 0.1
 )

congress_layer.addData(@congress_geojson)
```

This isn't working, and specifically (despite attempts to find other ways, the errors I'm getting in the console are:

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of      undefined
at o.GeoJSON.o.FeatureGroup.extend.addData (http://localhost:3000/packages/leaflet.js?ad7b569067d1f68c7403ea1c89a172b4cfd68d85:39:16471)
at Object.Template.map.rendered (http://localhost:3000/client/client.coffee.js?37b1cdc5945f3407f2726a5719e1459f44d1db2d:213:18)
```

I have no doubt that I'm missing something stupidly obvious here.  Any suggestions or tips for what I'm doing completely wrong would be appreciated.  Is it a case where an object globally declared in a .js file isn't available to code in a .coffee file?  Maybe I'm doing something wrong on the Meteor side?

Thanks!

Edit:

So I was able to get things working by putting the .js file containing the congress object in a root /lib folder, causing the object to load first, and then calling the congress object from the client.  However, I'm still wanting to know how I could simply share this object from the server?  What is the "Meteor way" here?

Comment: You can first try to define congress_geojson` within `client.coffee` file to confirm this is a scoping issue. Also, where does `features` come from? I don't see that in your code, so which library does it refer to? That may give you some additional clues.

Comment: Serkan, features is returned by the topojson.feature() function running on the congress object.  Also, already tried defining in client.  No dice.

Comment: "@ symbol there? I've been told this allows a variable in Coffeescript to be globally scoped?" No, `@` is simply an alias for `this`, which may or may not refer to the global context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the *Meteor* way to *order* the loading of files, use the [`Meteor.startup` function](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_startup) and put the initialization code there. That function is the [`$.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) of the Meteor world, i.e., it will execute only after all your files have been successfully loaded on the client.

So in your case:

```coffee
Meter.startup ->
    congress_layer.addData(@congress_geojson)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Meteor.startup wasn't helping me here, for the simple reason that depending on where it is, it does different things.  In the client, it runs when the DOM is done loading, while on the server, it runs when the files are moved. 
My issue is that I couldn't access the variable on the server because the object (which was created from a very large json file) wasn't fully loaded by the time the client DOM was loaded.  The solution to this was to place the .js files containing the objects in the /lib folder, which made them a priority in load order.